# it is possible to buy this pattent and use it in Colombia south america?

Tags: us20100175570

I would like to know more about this patent, likehow much it cost or if it is possible to work with it to produce new projects and products.

Comment: This site is not a good way to direct a question to the inventor. They are not likely to notice this question. US patents are only applicable within the U.S. As it happens, the specific document you mention is a patent application, not an issued patent. However it did later issue as an actual patent US  US7584909.

Comment: Hi, Ask Patents is a website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patent Applications and US Patents. Unfortunately, questions about copyright, trademark, and licensing are outside the scope of this site.